# How to bypass "Blocked call to navigator.vibrate because user hasn't tapped on the frame or any embedded frame yet"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have a use case where I need to use the `navigator.vibrate` API to vibrate once an image has finished sliding in from the side:

Code pen demo here: https://codepen.io/ifusion/pen/XeWqpj

**Note, this only seems to work on Android Google Chrome & Android Firefox**

However if the `navigator.vibrate` is not activated by an actual touch then in chrome throws an error in the console:

`[Intervention] Blocked call to navigator.vibrate because user hasn't tapped on the frame or any embedded frame yet: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5644273861001216.`

Samsung are using it at the end of the second step on this site: https://explorethenextgalaxy.com/ (Only works on android chrome & android firefox).

Screenshot at the point of it happening: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e8h7s3nzfwdk9dk/Screenshot%202017-09-13%2016.50.24.png?dl=0

I have had a look through their code and they are just using the `navigator.vibrate` just like I am and can't see them doing anything differently.

Is there a way to by pass this? I have tried `.click()` etc but the error still shows.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The vibrate API is only available once the user has started interacting with your page (e.g, by tapping or dragging on the screen). It cannot be used before a user interaction -- this is to prevent web pages (particularly embedded advertisements!) from attempting to scare the user by making their phone vibrate.

There is no way to bypass this, short of restructuring your page such that the user has to tap something before seeing that content.

Comment: Lifesaver, I have made it so you have to click a button which activates the animation and then once animation finishes the phone vibrates. Whoop! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Another way to this easily.

Disable this option on your chrome browser by going to

```
chrome://flags
```

and find option called :: **Requiring user gesture for the Vibration API** and change the value to **Disable**.

this will require reload your browser and now every thing work find.

Comment: This flag no longer exists.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(window.navigator.userAgentData.mobile){
    window.navigator.vibrate(100);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check if it's mobile

```
const isMobile: () => {
    const nav = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    return (
        nav.match(/iphone/i) || nav.match(/ipod/i) || nav.match(/ipad/i) || nav.match(/android/i)
    );
};

isMobile() && window.navigator.vibrate(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just faced this problem and found easy solution:

`window.navigator.vibrate && window.navigator.vibrate(100);`

using on event handler.

No more error console message.

Comment: Where or how did you find the solution you suggest? This information might be helpful for future reference.

Comment: @NicuVlad I can't remember what I ate for breakfast this morning. Image me trying to remember a javaScript problem from 2017! I hope you can fix your bugs :)